# Archive and export ipa with xcode

Tags: ios, xcode8, ipa

I build my project successfully with xcode 8.3.2, but if I want to export ipa application, the button 'export' always disabled[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHxg3.png)
Any idea

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the description box below "export", you must be enrolled in the developer program in order to distribute your apps. Either you havent selected your team in Xcode before archiving, or you arent a member.

Comment: I got active code with mail, but I could not active that thought from link activated 'Activation Code link'

Comment: Im not too familiar with setting up accounts, its been a while since I did my own. Get the link resent and try again, and a quick search online should show you exactly how to get your account hooked up in Xcode